# How to make a variable in Typescript not use this

Tags: javascript, typescript, this

I need to make a TS variable to get the outer this context into a function as that so I can make a call off it.

```
    public that = this;

    constructor() {
        $('#start').click(function(){
            $(this).hide();
            that.createLoader();
        });
    }
```

Results in this JS,

```
    function SpaceInvaders() {
        this.that = this;
        $('#start').click(function () {
            $(this).hide();
            this.that.createLoader();
        });
    }
```

As you can see the generate code results in `this.that.cretaeLoader()` which is actually, the Jquery DOM element.

I am new to TS please could you help

Comment: The TypeScript compiler never inserts `this.` in front of expressions like what you're showing here. Are you sure that the code you posted is what you actually have? Can you post an example that would compile in the Playground (http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/) ?

Answer (score 4):

Declare `that` inside the `constructor`:

```
constructor() {
    var that = this;
    $('#start').click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        that.createLoader();
    });
}
```

Comment: Silly me, need more coffee :)

Answer (score 4):

The alternative would be to use some "bound to context" function

```
declare var $:any;
class MyClass {

    createLoader(){}

    constructor() {
        $('#start').click((e)=>{
            $(e.currentTarget).hide();
            this.createLoader();
        });
    }
}
```

[see exemple](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground#src=declare%20var%20%24%3aany;%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%09createLoader%28%29%7B%0A%09%09%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28%27#start%27%29.click%28%28e%29=%3E%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28e.currentTarget%29.hide%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.createLoader%28%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0A)

Comment: Side note for those who use this, "event.currentTarget" isn't always the same as "this" so be mindful of where you use it